# Regex parse a list from a string starting with a specific character

Tags: c++, regex

Is there a way to parse this lines?
line #1

```
f 1/2/3
```

line #2

```
f 1/2/3 4/5/6 7/8/9 10/11/12
```

I need a check if the string is starting with a letter `f` and then patterns `(\d+)\/(\d+)\/(\d+)` repeat delimited with a space

I want to get matches **1**/**2**/**3** for the line #1
I want to get matches **1**/**2**/**3** **4**/**5**/**6** **7**/**8**/**9** **10**/**11**/**12** for the line #2

Comment: No, not with regex, but tag it with a programming language (i.e. python, JavaScript etc)

Comment: @allanwind why? It's purely regex issue, isn't it?

Comment: You can use this: `(?<=^f\s)(\d+)\/(\d+)\/(\d+)`

Comment: @Herrgott. It could be, but it's much easier to solve without.

Comment: @alireza it matches only the first occurrence of the pattern https://regex101.com/r/4vScSn/1

Comment: No, regex mean regular expression,  you need something to execute it.

Comment: Are you willing to apply a series of regex?

Comment: If using PCRE use: `(?:^f|(?!^)\G)\h+\K(?:\d+/\d+/\d+)`

Comment: @madphysicist i want to get an array of matches of given patterns which simple `((\d)\/(\d)\/(\d))` gives me but i also want to make sure if the string is starting with an `f` character

Comment: If this is not a pure regex task (string to string), and you want an array or list of something, you need a language tag.

Comment: Do the segments all have the same length of 3, or are you looking for variable-length sub-lists?

Comment: @anubhava your regex works just fine but i don't know which syntax does c++'s std::regex uses

Comment: https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/ECMAScript/

Comment: @madphysicist yes, it is always 3 numbers delimited with a `/` that whole can be repeated one or more times. @anubhava gave me a regex that works like I want https://regex101.com/r/BbIKCY/1, it's time to check which regex syntax does c++ std uses and adopt it to

Comment: @Herrgott: You can try: `(?:^f|(?!^)\G)\s+(\d+/\d+/\d+)` in C#

Comment: @Herrgott. That just performs validation. It doesn't get you an array of values.

Comment: @Herrgott `std::regex` only allows a specific ECMAScript support. Ther regex101.com  does not support this regex flavor now, its ECMAScript support is that of JavaScript. The PCRE regex will work with `boost::regex`. Also, do you want to get anything from a string like `f 1/2/3 xxx`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew no, that string is considered malformed and no matches should occur

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can parse it with regex in c++ like this.
it is not completely done like normal regex in the
sense that you need to force c++ to find multiple
groups from a while loop.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

struct numbers_t
{
    numbers_t(int n1, int n2, int n3) : v1{ n1 }, v2{ n2 }, v3{ n3 } {}

    int v1;
    int v2;
    int v3;
};

auto parse_number_groups(const std::string& input)
{
    static std::regex line_starts_with_f_and_space{ "^f " };
    static std::regex number_group("(\\d+)/(\\d+)/(\\d+)");
    static std::smatch match;

    std::vector<numbers_t> output;

    if (std::regex_search(input, line_starts_with_f_and_space))
    {
        std::string::const_iterator cbegin(input.cbegin());
        while (std::regex_search(cbegin, input.cend(), match, number_group))
        {
            // match [0] is the whole match, match[1] to match[3] are the subgroups. (check in debugger)
            output.emplace_back(std::stoi(match[1]), std::stoi(match[2]), std::stoi(match[3]));
            cbegin = match.suffix().first;
        }
    }

    return output;
}

int main()
{
    auto number_groups = parse_number_groups("f 1/2/3 4/5/6 7/8/9 10/11/12");
    for (const auto& number_group : number_groups)
    {
        std::cout << number_group.v1 << ", " << number_group.v2 << ", " << number_group.v3 << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As `f 1/2/3 xxx` [should result in no matches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69135720/regex-parse-a-list-from-a-string-starting-with-a-specific-character?noredirect=1#comment122199282_69135720), there are two operations you need to perform:

- Validate the string against the pattern that validates your string format
- Extract space-separated tokens.

The validation part can be achieved with a regex like

```cpp
^f\s+(\d+/\d+/\d+(?:\s+\d+/\d+/\d+)*)$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/y8HiHW/1/). *NOTE*: a shorter variant [would be ideal](https://regex101.com/r/y8HiHW/2), `^f((?:\s+\d+/\d+/\d+)+)$`, but it captures into Group 1 the space after `f`, while it is more convenient here to trim the Group 1 value with the regex itself. *Details*:

- `^` - start of string (NOTE: it is not necessary when using the regex with `std::regex_match` as this method anchors the match at the start and end of string by default)
- `f`  - an `f` char
- `\s+`  - one or more whitespaces
- `(\d+/\d+/\d+(?:\s+\d+/\d+/\d+)*)` - Group 1: one or more digits and then two occurrences of `/` and one or more digits, and then zero or more occurrences of one or more whitespaces, one or more digits and then two occurrences of `/` and one or more digits
- `$` - end of string (NOTE: not necessary when using the regex with `std::regex_match` again).

Next step is to get the Group 1 value and split it with whitespaces. Yes, you may use a regex iterator to extract the `\d+/\d+/\d+` matches, but you may in fact use the fact the string will be just a list of space-separated tokens and avoid using the second regex.

Here is the [full C++ code demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cd9274c6a3afd1c8):

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <regex>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
    const std::regex valRegex(R"(f\s+(\d+/\d+/\d+(?:\s+\d+/\d+/\d+)*))");
    // const std::string foo = "f 1/2/3 4/5/6 7/8/9 10/11/12 xxx"; // => The 'f 1/2/3 4/5/6 7/8/9 10/11/12 xxx' string is not valid!
    const std::string foo = "f 1/2/3 4/5/6 7/8/9 10/11/12"; // => ["1/2/3", "4/5/6", "7/8/9", "10/11/12"]
    std::smatch m;
    if (std::regex_match(foo, m, valRegex)) { // Run full string match
        std::istringstream iss(m[1].str());   // If matched, split 
        std::vector<std::string> tokens;      //   Group 1 with whitespaces
        copy(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(iss),
             std::istream_iterator<std::string>(),
             std::back_inserter(tokens));
        for(auto &s: tokens) {                // Demo token output
            std::cout << s << std::endl;
        }
    } else {
        std::cout << "The '" << foo << "' string is not valid!" << std::endl;
    }
}
```